# Silverlight 4, TreeView Drag/Drop. Drop Confirmation followed by Cancel

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, treeview

If I'm 'Drop'ing a TreeView node onto another Node. At the end of a Drag/Drop operation, I want to prompt the user to 'Confirm' the Drop, and then cancel/undo the Drop if they cancel.

This confirmation is currently in the Drop operation event , ie by opening a child window. However by the time the user confirms one way or the other, the event will already have finished and so I don't have an opportunity to 'Cancel' in the normal way? ie...

```
itemDragArgs.Cancel = true;
itemDragArgs.Handled = true;
```

Has anyone had any experience with such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a similar scenario with some other controls in which,

- The dropped *Node* is ignored (cancelled & handled = true) but keep the reference of the node (in an `object` field or smth)
- upon confirmation, add the object to the node.

Something like this would be of any help?